# bash command `cd /usr/local/src` (including backticks) has no effect

Tags: bash

I am fairly new to bash, so I don't know where this problem is appearing. 
But, I have this script, which is supposed to just change cd, download a tar file and extract it. 
I am applying this command from `/home/`

```
#!/bin/bash
`cd /usr/local/src`
`wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz -O nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz`
`tar -xzf  nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz`
```

So, this download the tar file and extracts in home, instead of in `/usr/local/src`

I have read that this might be a problem from the `cd` command, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Notice the stray `"` at the end of the `cd` command?

Comment: If that's really in the script it wouldn't run at all.

Comment: also, if you want your script to fail and exit if anything doesn't succeed, put a `set -e` at the top, or make it `#!/bin/bash -e`.

Comment: You are probably running this as a user, not as root, you probably are not able to write to /usr/local/src as user. Try executing these commands directly on the CLI and you will see the issue.

Comment: @Barmar, ...meaning we haven't been given a full and accurate copy of the code.

Comment: @JNevill If it doesn't have access it will report an error, not extract into the home directory.

Comment: @Barmar, not if it doesn't have `+x` on `/usr/local/src`; in that case the `cd` will just fail. This is why I suggested `set -e`.

Comment: Sorry guys, the `"` is a typo

Comment: @JNevill I am running it as root

Comment: @Bimlik1, ...and again, what happens with `set -e`? If it fails at the `cd`, instead of proceeding to `wget`, then we have our answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, this was just an example, but the problem is very similar to the question

Comment: @Bimlik1, test that the ACTUAL CODE YOU PROVIDED HERE reproduces the problem.

Comment: Oh. The backticks will stop your `cd` from working, for sure. Take those out.

Comment: ...take them out *everywhere*; running `\`command\`` first runs `command` in a subshell, READS THAT COMMAND'S OUTPUT, and then runs the first command's output as a second command. Is that **really** what you want?

Comment: Also, because it makes the first command run in a subshell, things like `cd` don't impact your real outer shell, because their effects are isolated.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy with `set -e` enabled I get ` foo.sh line 6: Loaded: command not found` line 6 is ``yum -y update``

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't know what you mean, the question itself shows what I want. I just want to cd to specific dir, download and extract. that's all

Comment: You get that because the output from `yum` uses the string `Loaded`, and because you're using extra backticks, that output is being run as its own command.

Comment: If that's all you want, why are you writing `\`cd /usr/local/src\`` instead of just `cd /usr/local/src`? You're telling the shell to do extra stuff, and that extra stuff breaks your script.

Comment: By the way -- you _got_ that same error earlier; `set -e` just made the script stop when it happened, so you could actually see it, instead of keeping going and letting it get lost in the noise. :)

Comment: Working with root privileges is dangerous.  It is particularly dangerous when working with untested scripts.  Be extremely cautious about using root privileges — don't use them unless you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As edited, your script now says that you're running

```
#!/bin/bash
`cd /usr/local/src`
`wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz -O nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz`
`tar -xzf  nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz`
```

The backticks cause each command to be run in a subshell; and each subshell's output to be read, string-split, and run as a second command.

Also, because the `cd` is in a subshell, its effects don't carry over to the main shell.

---

So: Remove the backticks (and make sure your script exits if the `cd` fails; I do this here with the `-e` flag). You should only be running:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz -O nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf  nginx-1.6.2.tar.gz
```

...which is to say: Your commands **must not start and end with ` characters**.

Comment: Thanks. I thought all bash commands should be enclosed with backticks

Comment: Absolutely not. Backticks do what's called "command substitution"; they run what's within them as a command, and then replace themselves with that command's output, running the result of that substitution as a new command. They're also deprecated -- the newer and preferred syntax for command substitution is `$(foo)` rather than `\`foo\``.